# Hibernate Criteria builder IN clause query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

How to write criteria builder api query in Hibernate for below given query? batchId is not a primary key & not unique.

> SELECT * FROM User WHERE batchID IN ('1', '3')

I've tried:

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> userRoot = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);

    List<Integer> batchIdList = new ArrayList<>();
    batchIdList.add(1);
    batchIdList.add(3);

    Predicate queryPredicate = builder.in(userRoot.get(User_.batchId).in(batchIdList)); 

    criteriaQuery.select(userRoot);
    criteriaQuery.where(queryPredicate);

    TypedQuery<User> userQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

    List<User> userResult = userQuery.getResultList();
```

I get nothing but the data exists in the database.

Comment: "I get nothing". Yes you do, you get SQL executed, and you can look at what SQL was generated, and that tells you if your Criteria is erroneous. Have you looked?

Comment: Enable hibernate debug log and see what query it generates.  Its simple as that. But from the code you posted, that look okay. Unless you have column name mappings incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Use this. I assume that your batchId is `Integer`.

```
 CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> userRoot = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
         criteriaQuery.select(userRoot);    

        List<Integer> batchIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        batchIdList.add(1);
        batchIdList.add(3);
        criteriaQuery            
  .where(builder.and(userRoot.get(User_.batchId).in(batchIdList)));
        TypedQuery<User> userQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

        List<User> userResult = userQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: @newguy try updated answer now. hopefully it works fine and make sure your databse hace recordes with batch id 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Working example of IN clause in criteria query of Hiberbate 5.3 and above.

Below example find the data of employees have name in (sumit,amit,vivek) and age 24.

```
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Expression;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;


public void getCriteria() {

        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = getSessionfactory().openSession();
            CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Employee> criteria = builder.createQuery(Employee.class);
            Root<Employee> root = criteria.from(Employee.class);
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
            predicates.add(builder.in(root.get("name")).value("sumit").value("amit").value("vivek"));   // IN clause
            predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("age"),24));
            criteria.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
            List<Employee> employeeList = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```